# FactoryGirl and acts_as_tree using after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a class named MenuHeader with the following:

```
class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree :parent_id
  belongs_to :menu
```

I'd like to create several levels of menu_headers but am not sure how to do this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :menu_header do
    name "my menu header"
    menu
    after(:create) { |menu_header| do_something_else_to(user) }
  end
end
```

Would I create a :menu_header2 or can I some how just extend the above. How do I set the :parent_id to the value of the recently created menu_header?

thx

Comment: can you explain in detail. Your ques is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create different level of menu_header factories and `build` their children using `after(:build)`. btw I prefer `after :build` because I can easily create non-persisted objects for testing.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :menu_header do
    name "my menu header"
    menu

    factory :menu_header_level1 do
      after(:build) do |m|
        m.children << FactoryGirl.build(:menu_header, :name => 'level0 submenu0', :parent => m)
        m.children << FactoryGirl.build(:menu_header, :name => 'level0 submenu1', :parent => m)
      end
    end

    factory :menu_header_level2 do
      after(:build) do |m|
        m.children << FactoryGirl.build(:menu_header_level1, :name => 'level1 submenu0', :parent => m)

      end
    end   
  end
end
```